# How to use 2 video outputs(videoFile&videoData) in AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, video-capture, avcapturesession

I need to make recorder with ability to capture some frames.
Now all I tried is to set AVCaptureSession with 2 inputs(audio and video) and 2 outputs:

```
    //configure output to writeVideo
self.movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
[self.session addOutput:self.movieFileOutput];

self.videoDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

[self.videoDataOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];

// Configure output to catch frames.
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
[self.videoDataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
[self.session addOutput:self.videoDataOutput];
```

in interface file I conform class to protocols AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate. Writing in file works perfect but method

```
    - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

is never called. 
In case when I remove [self.session addOutput:self.movieFileOutput]; line so that there is only self.videoDataOutput in sessions outputs. 
capturing imagies works perfect.

How can I configure videoInput in this two outputs.

Thanks for all advices you'll give=)